# Removing a list from repeated members using list comprehension instead of the usual for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have learned that I can use the so-called list comprehension to make python 'for loops' shorter if I want to create a list. For example, instead of writing:

```
b = []
a = [2, 3, 5]
for x in a:
    b.append(x**2)
```

I can write my code like this:

```
b = [x**2 for x in a]
```

I was wondering how can I convert the below code to the second shorter format:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
u_lst = []
for x in lst:
    if x not in u_lst:
        u_lst.append(x)
```

Comment: not all loops can be converted to list comprehensions in ways that make sense. list comprehensions are best suited when you need to "map/do something on every value" in a list, or "filter/select specific items based on independent conditions" in a list, or some combination thereof. list comprehensions are best suited when you want to create a list as an output. Here, your list under construction itself is involved in the conditional. That doesn't resolve to a clean comprehension and a normal loop may simply make more sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PritoshSingh has pointed out in the comment, a list construction that involves references to items already constructed in the same list is not suitable for the use of a list comprehension, which is best for value mapping and/or filtering based on conditions not involving the list being constructed itself.

The problem you're describing can be best solved by using the `dict.from_keys` method, which ignores items it has already *seen* as it reads from the given sequence:

```
u_list = list(dict.from_keys(lst))
```

Use `collections.OrderedDict` in place of `dict` if you're using Python 3.6 or earlier versions, where order of dict keys is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

From the specific example given it seems like you want `u_lst` to be a list of unique values only. If so, there is no need for any list comprehensions, just use a `set` on the original list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
u_lst = list(set(lst))
```

Outputs `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` without converting into a list and `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` with it.

Note that using `set` on a list produces a set, to get it to behave as a list, you would then convert it into a list as above.